# How to add custom attribute in magento2.1 customer panel wishlist section?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-account, wishlist

I want to add guaranty **(custom product attribute)** to **customers wish-list page** that is in **customer dashboard** in my **Wishlist tab**. Means that I wanted to show `price`, `qty`, `name`, `guaranty`, and `add to basket` into the products section in **customers Wishlist** tab.

I am using Magento 2.1.

How can I do that?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question a little more with some image or some code content so that someone can help you better

Comment: Yes! i want to add guaranty attribute that is my custom attribute to my wishlist page in customer panel my wishlist tab. means that i want to show price qty name guaranty and add to basket into my products who are in my wishlist tab

Comment: @MGPM guaranty is product attribute or custom option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the custom attribute value on the wishlist section of customer dashboard do the following thing

- From admin panel go to the below location

> Admin_panel > STORES > Attributes > Products > select the attribute

- Go to the storefront properties please [refer this](https://www.screencast.com/t/yVjQRzHmb)
- Look for the **Used in Product Listing** change it to **yes** please [refer this](https://www.screencast.com/t/Vqdk4Zgd)
- Save the attribute
- Now copy the **`name.phtml`** file from the below location

> magento_root/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/view/frontend/templates/item/column/name.phtml

- Paste it to the below location

> magento_root/app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Wishlist/templates/item/column/name.phtml

- Paste the below code to the newly created name.phtml

**name.phtml**

```
<?php if(!empty($product)) : ?>
   <?php $attributeValue = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('attibute_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
   $attributeLabel = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('attibute_name')->getFrontend()->getLabel($product);
   if(!empty($attributeValue)) { ?>
     <h2 class="product-<?php echo $attributeLabel?>"><strong><?php echo __($attributeLabel);?></strong>  <?php echo __($attributeValue); ?></h2>
   <?php } 
endif; ?>
```

> Note: Replace the attribute_name with the name of your attribute that
>   you can copy from the Admin panel.
>
> You can also use some other phtml file but make sure to call it using the layout.xml file for the wishlist you can use `wishlist_index_index.xml` file
>
> If the content is not loading then to flush the cache run the below
>   command
>
> ```
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```